# How to organize library class structure

Tags: c#, class, organization

I have a controller circuit that I can communicate with via serial port and I would like to write a class library for it. I figured it is far easier calling a method (and far more readable) than repeatedly hard-coding lengthy character strings. Anyway, the controller comes pre-programmed with ~100 get/set functions separated into three categories: Sensor Settings, Output Settings, and Environment Settings. These functions are used to get or set the controller's settings. I was wondering what the "best" or "accepted" class organization would be?

All the functions belong to the same controller and use the same serial port so I figured that `Controller` would be the top level class. Within this class, I setup a `SerialPort` instance and created a simple send/receive method using the instance: `string SendReceive(string commandString)`.

Because I really don't want to have ~100 functions and properties in the single class, I tried creating some nested classes (`SensorSettings`, `OutputSettings`, and `EnvironmentSettings`) and placing the respective functions within them. When I tried to build, however, I received a compile error stating that I attempted to access a higher level, non-static method (`SendReceive(string commandString)`) from within one of the nested classes.

Each of the various methods has a unique and variable send/receive command so I would create the command string within the method, call `SendReceive`, and process the returning command. Is there any way to do this?

I would like to use properties to work my way down to get/set the various settings. For example...

`controllerInstance.SensorSettingsProperty.Units;  // Units in use.`

or...

`controllerInstance.OutputSettingsProperty.GetOutput(sensor1);  // Get sensor 1 output.`

...but all of these require the use of the same serial port and `SendRecieve`.

Comment: So, each "function" is a command you can send?

Comment: Yes. For example, I created a method `double GetSensorOUT(int sensorNum)` to return the sensor reading at sensor "x" = `sensorNum`. Within this method I create the command "SR,HB,B,xx,\r" and try to send using `SendRecieve("...")`. There are ~100 of these "SR,HB,..." type "functions" and I wrote a method for each one. Hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to make objects for each command, and then use your controller to send commands.

Example:

```
 public class GetSensorReadingCommand
 {
      public GetSensorReadingCommand(Sensor sensor, SerialController controller)
      {
          // Set up command
      }

      public int Execute()
      {
          // Call controller.SendReceive with whatever, get or send stuff
      }
 }
```

Then you would simply make new objects every time you want to do a function.

```
 SerialController controller = new SerialController(somePortNumber);
 GetSensorReadingCommand command = new GetSensorReadingCommand(Sensor.Sensor10, controller);
 int reading = command.Execute();
```

You would follow a pattern like that for each command you can send. If it's not a known at compile type sensor number, instead of using an enum, provide an integer.

You'll end up with a lot of small code files instead of a bunch of large ones. In addition, you can tailor each command with logic specific to it's functioning.